# Error while installing Airflow using pip in windows- Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-c++, pip, setup.py

I was trying to install Airflow in windows through command prompt using pip.

The python is 3.4.2, pip included. I am getting the below error.

`distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).`

I have installed Visual studio 2012 but Python 3.4 looks for VS10 by default. I tried to trick Python to use the newer visual studio by

1. Executing the command `set VS100COMNTOOLS=%VS110COMNTOOLS%`.
2. Adding new system variable `VS100COMNTOOLS` as variable name and gave the value as `VS110COMNTOOLS`.

Both tricks did not work. I am still getting the same old error.

The file `vcvarsall.bat` is present in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC`

what is missing here? how can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `VS100COMNTOOLS=%VS110COMNTOOLS%` in cmd, i did
`SET VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\` and it was picking correctly but again thrown another pile of errors as VS11 compiler is different and cannot compile Python 3.4 code properly.

I uninstalled VS11, Installed VS10 and it worked.